# Use of BLOB giving "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.sql.BLOB" in case of SPRING-Hibernate application in case of ORACLE as a database!

Tags: java, oracle, blob

I am using BLOBs in my SPRING-Hibernate application its, giving "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.sql.BLOB" in case of ORACLE as a database!

Exactly I am getting following:

```
Caused by: 
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Couldn't initialize OracleLobHandler because Oracle driver classes are not available. Note that OracleLobHandler requires Oracle JDBC driver 9i or higher!
nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.sql.BLOB
```

Comment: I tried with all the ORACLE JDBC dirver versions [9i and 10g] almost all the releases!
If you can tell me the specific version then that will be great!

Comment: how did you try? How do you put them on your classpath? Where is your configuration?

Comment: In fact I am using OSGI, so I create a bundle wrapper and put it into the classpath!

Comment: then you have classpath issues with OSGi.

Comment: But it is able to load other classes from ORACLE jdbc driver!
I mean everything else apart from BLOB stuff works properly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe your OSGI manifest does not export the right packages?

Answer (score 3):

You need `ojdbc.jar` (or similar) on your classpath (this is the Oracle JDBC driver)

[Here is a list of drivers](http://www.oracle.com/technology/software/tech/java/sqlj_jdbc/index.html), pick the one that suits your environment.